# Why isn't Vue reading my entire JSON object that I'm passing down through PHP as a prop?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, vue.js

I'm attempting to pass a JSON object down into a Vue component using a prop. The JSON object is computed using `json_encode()` on a WordPress query that gathers all posts for the page. I'm then using the PHP function `addcslashes()` to escape all of my double quotes.

When I use `echo` on this variable, this is the output:

`{\"ID\":185,\"post_author\":\"1\",\"post_date\":\"2016-02-23   14:32:45\",\"post_date_gmt\":\"2016-02-23 14:32:45\"}`

However, when I pass the JSON string down to my Vue prop, all the Vue debugger spits out is `testprop: "{\\"`.

Any idea as to why I can't get the full JSON object string within the Vue prop?

```
$newsPostQuery = new WP_Query($args); 
$posts = $newsPostQuery->posts[0];
$posts = json_encode($posts);
$posts = addcslashes($posts, '"');
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($posts);
echo "</pre>";
echo $posts;
?>

<testposts testprop="<?php echo $posts; ?>"
></testposts>

<script type="text/javascript">

    new Vue({
        el: '.News-Feed',
        components: {
            testposts: {
                template: '#test-posts',
                props: ['testprop'],
                ready() {
                    console.log(this.testprop);
                    this.testprop = JSON.parse(this.testprop);
                },
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried without the escaping the quotes, but the Vue prop only spits out `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the official vue.js "way" but here's how I handle preloading data.

First just grab your result set, don't worry about any encoding/escaping yet:

```
$newsPostQuery = new WP_Query($args); 
$posts = $newsPostQuery->posts[0];
```

Now in javascript, create a global variable for this preloaded data. Sometimes I use an object so I can easily add more variables later if needed:

```
<script>
var preloaded = {
    'posts' : <?php echo json_encode($posts) ?>;
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about escaping, there are no issues with quotes. The `json_encode` method is enough.

Now in your vue.js code, you can refer to `preloaded.posts` when you want to access this data, instead of trying to access via a prop.

Props are great for simple scalar values. But it gets messy fast with objects/json like this.

Comment: Ma mannnn. This works well, never thought of this, thanks a ton.

Comment: Yeah sure thing, I tried earlier, but the time limit prevented me from marking it.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone stumbling on this questions, an alternative approach to the accepted answer is to use the following to generate a string for use in a prop:

```
htmlentities(json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_QUOT), ENT_QUOTES);
```

if you wanted you could wrap this un a function like so:

```
function jsonToProp($data)
{
    return htmlentities(json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_QUOT), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

stick that in you functions.php file. the call use it with your vue component:

```
$posts = ...generate an array of data you want to pass into your component

<testposts :testprop="<?= jsonToProp($posts);?>"></testposts>
```

Note the colon : in front of the prop - you need this or vue will assume the content should be parsed as a string rather than as a data object.

Hope this helps!